# Populating multiple fields from string using Update Cursor?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, splitting

I am trying to split up a comment field from a csv (or a dbf) into three different groups. The comment field is similar to this :

```
 Pa=68781/Rh=44.31/Ti=-7.56 AWEC Space Agency
```

I want to split it up so that three new fields (already created but empty) are populated by the Pa, Rh, and Ti values from each row.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach that relies heavily on [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split). This script assumes you have created 4 fields: `("comment", "Pa", "Rh", "Ti")`

1. Split the string by a space character `['Pa=68781/Rh=44.31/Ti=-7.56', 'AWEC', 'Space', 'Agency']`
2. Select the first list item `['Pa=68781/Rh=44.31/Ti=-7.56']`
3. Split again by `/`: `['Pa=68781', 'Rh=44.31', 'Ti=-7.56']`
4. For each pertinent field, split again by `=` and write those values
   to the correct field

---

```
import arcpy

dbf = r'C:\path\to\your\dbffile.dbf'

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(dbf, ("comment", "Pa", "Rh", "Ti")) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        # First split string into parts
        parts = row[0].split(" ")[0].split("/")
        row[1] = parts[0].split("=")[1]
        row[2] = parts[1].split("=")[1]
        row[3] = parts[2].split("=")[1]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: thank you for your reply! unfortunately, I am getting the following error :

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/GEOM4020/Project1_Data/Script.py", line 23, in <module>
    for row in cursor:
RuntimeError: create cursor has failed

Comment: Do you have the following field names created: `"Original", "Pa", "Rh", "Ti"`? `Original` should be the string you need to split, e.g. `Pa=68781/Rh=44.31/Ti=-7.56 AWEC Space Agency`.

Comment: my "Original" is titled "comment", and I've changed that so it shouldn't be giving me this problem. I'm getting an error on my "for row in cursor:" line..

Comment: # imports the arcPy site package for ArcGIS functionality
import arcpy

csv = r'D:\GEOM4020\Project1_Data\BalloonData_edited.csv'

#cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(csv, ("comment", "Pa", "Rh", "Ti"))

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(csv, ("comment", "Pa", "Rh", "Ti")) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        parts = row[0].split(" ")[0].split("/")
        row[1] = parts[0].split("=")[1]
        row[2] = parts[1].split("=")[1]
        row[3] = parts[2].split("=")[1]
        cursor.updateRow(row)

Comment: Could you please try using a dbf file instead?

Comment: thanks for your help! I'm really lost...creating dbf now

Comment: I edited the question to use a dbf file, which I successfully tested.

Comment: IT WORKED! Thank you so much! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @DaveTrenholm If this solved your problem, you should upvote it and also click the checkmark to mark this as the Accepted answer, then future visitors know that this solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You tag *arcpy* and *cursor*  but your question does not specifically ask for an arcpy solution.  You can populate your new fields using the field calculator and some Python code without having to rely on arcpy cursors. 
In this example I just split the string up in your example, extract out the number parts and convert them to numbers.
I do not know what your column headings are called, nor what type of file it is, so that will alter the final code. You can figure that out.

[Here is a link](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm) to using Python within the field calculator in ArcGIS 10.3.

Here is some simple code to follow.

```
foo = r"Pa=68781/Rh=44.31/Ti=-7.56 AWEC Space Agency"
splitfoo = foo.split("/")
Pa = float(splitfoo[0].split("=")[1])
Rh = float(splitfoo[1].split("=")[1])
Ti = (splitfoo[2].split("=")[1])
Ti = float(Ti.strip("AWEC Space Agency"))
```